# Insertar varias fechas para un mismo id - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

Necesito ingresar un mes completo para cada campo "ID" a fin de verificar si una habitación de un hotel está disponible en tal fecha.
Sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así sucesivamente para cada una de las 500 habitaciones de un hotel.
Estoy usando SQLServer Express 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @habId INT = 1, @contador INT = 0, @fechaInital as datetime;
WHILE @habId < 5
BEGIN

    SET @fechaInital = '20170601'
    WHILE @contador < 30
    BEGIN
       print '' + convert(nvarchar(2), @habId) +', ' + convert(nvarchar(10), @fechaInital)

       SET @fechaInital = DATEADD(day, 1, @fechaInital)
       SET @contador = @contador + 1;
    END;

    SET @habId = @habId + 1;
    SET @contador = 0
END;
```

Imagen resultante:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta función va a imprimir X fecha, desde Junio 1, hasta 30 días después. En tu caso, en lugar de imprimir, deberá hacer un **INSERT** y supongo que darle tu propio formato, etc.

Puedes usar dos bucles **for** anidados (uno que primero dispone de las 500 habitaciones y otro con los 30 días) y listo.

Comment: Excelente!! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda José me funcionó perfecto!!!

Comment: Una mejora @José Cordero: para completar exactamente la cantidad de días del mes (contemplando los casos de 28/29/30 y 31 días) se puede contar los días desde el primer día hasta el último haciendo esto: `SELECT @contador = DATEDIFF(DAY, @fechaInital, DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(@fechaInital ) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(@fechaInital ), -1))  + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Requieres hacer una tabla con la siguiente estructura

```
Id int, // Id de la nueva tabla
Habitacion_Id int,  // Foranea con tu tabla, Id de la fecha en la que quieres poner muchas fechas
Fecha datetime // La fecha que quieres colocar
```

Si deseas poner mas información modifica esa tabla

Comment: La tabla ya la tengo creada, solo tengo que INSERTAR las fechas (por ej.: del 01/06/2017 al 30/06/2017) para cada Habitación_Id

Comment: Podrías mostrar una parte de tu código con el que haces las inserciones y la estructura de tablas que ocupas para las habitaciones, para saber que avance tienes y poder guiarte.

Comment: Lo único que tengo es una FK a la tabla Habitaciones, la cual tiene los campos: Codigo_habitacion, Codigo_hotel, Nro_habitacion, Codigo_categoria, Capacidad_maxima. La tabla Habitaciones ya tiene la información con cada una de las habitaciones (son 540 en total)